Identify rear derailleur (Shimano 105 - medium or short)
I have a Shimano 105 5800 series rear derailleur, I am trying to find out cage length. The model name stamped on the underside of the mech just says "RD-5800", and elsewhere also "ML", I can't see either SS or GS anywhere. Any suggestions?
The cassette is 28-11 so my initial guess was that this is short cage, since that is sufficient for that range. But comparing the pictures, it looks more like the medium cage (and I believe there is no long cage in this range).
Model name stamp:

Overall picture:


I'm not sure where to find the stampings that say the model number. I do concur that this is a medium cage RD, and I think visual identification is enough. Short cage RDs are quite short.
The medium cage RD can officially handle large cogs of 28t to 32t. It is likely that it would do fine with a 34t big cog. Remember that Shimano didn't have a road cassette ending in -34 for this generation. The short cage RD maxed out at 28t; I would bet it would tolerate a 30t.

I believe the cage is interchangeable - so any stampings on the main body would be for the mech only and the cage would have its own marking.

An approximation:

SS short cage - they look really short especially when not installed.  SS have a distance between the two jockey wheels of under 70mm measuring from center to center of axles/bolts.
GS medium cage - Whatever falls in between 70mm and 100mm in length.
SGS long cage  - these look ridiculously long and can sometimes be a little flimsy because of their length and leverage.  Anything with a center-to-center distance of 100mm or more is a long-cage.  Folding bikes and 20" bikes risk dragging a long cage on the ground when leaning to the right.

These measurements are based off a quick google and also measuring a couple bikes I have handy.
For your photo it is either a medium or long cage, scale is hard to tell in the photo.

SGS is MTB only, I think. For the GRX group, the RD gets a whole different model number instead of the SGS designation.
